# setting up a samba PDC -error with testparm

Tags: linux, samba, ldap, openldap, domain-controller

I have installed a samba PDC but when I test the samba configurations file I am getting errors like these, "Invalid combination of parameters for service homes.         Map system can only work if create mask includes octal 010 (S_IXGRP)."

My Configuration file is as follows

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
 path = /home_srv1/%u
 valid users = %S
 read only = No
 create mask = 0660
 directory mask = 0770
 browseable = No
```

I tried to google but with no luck, Serverfault is always my best hope.

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the 'create mask' must include the binary 1 in the mask. `create mask` is an octal representation of the POSIX rights. The error message is telling you that 'group' requires 'execute' permissions for it to be valid.

1 = ..x
2 = .w.
3 = .wx
4 = r..
5 = r.x
6 = rw.
7 = rwx

A correctly formed "create mask" would look like `create mask 0670`.

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks a million! I used 770 instead.

Answer (score 0):

`valid users = %S` is redundant, you can safely remove it

Comment: Well thanks for you response but nothing has changed.